# How to achieve these kind of horizontal scrollable card designs

Tags: android, android-cardview

How can I achieve these kind of horizontal scroll-able card designs where at the beginning  first card is one step a head from image and after first scroll the image will become transparent and first card will take place the image

[image: Play Store screenshot][image: Play Store ScreenShot 2]

Answer (score 0):

these are material design `Cards` in a "contained collection" see [card collections](https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#card-collections)

... and that one "parent-child" transition can be found below paragraph [behavior](https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#behavior).

Comment: But which layout I should use and how I will set that transition and what about back ground and the last thing how I will do this with recyclerview?

Comment: @RANAJEETBARIK it's called `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`... can be used in a `RecyclerView` just alike the regular `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`.